# What happens if I overload a load balancer? Can I have two load balancers, and how would I set this up?

Tags: nginx, load-balancing

I have a question about scalability. Here's what I know so far:

*If I have an application that exceeds the provision of a single machine, it's possible to scale horizontally by adding additional machines. A load balancer would distribute traffic among those machines.*

However, what happens when the load balancer gets overloaded? Could anyone provide an explanation about how I could set up a second load balancer using NGINX?